# How to handle touch events on a parent view?

Tags: android, touch, android-linearlayout, ontouchlistener

I have a layout as :

```
LinearLayout
    TextView
    TextView
```

I want to look for gestures on the parent layout i.e. LinearLayout. But failed to do so.
Here is what I have tried :

```
 mll1.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        System.out.println("MASTERRRRRRRRRRR");
        selectedView = v;
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    });

    binding.result.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        return false;
    });

    binding.input.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: This should work. Put some logs into GestureDetector methods and check self.